# Ruby Kernel::system, negation pattern in shell command not working as expected

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, pattern-matching

The following bash command removes all hidden files from a directory called `foo` (excludes `.` and `..`):

```
rm -rf foo/.[^.]*
```

I would expect that passing this same command to Ruby's `Kernel::system` should do the same thing:

```
system("rm -rf foo/.[^.]*")
```

However, the above Ruby code returns `false` and produces this:

```
rm: cannot remove `..' directory `foo/..'
```

---

If I try it this way:

```
system("rm", "-rf", "foo/.[^.]*")
```

Then it returns `true`, but does not delete anything.

---

If I do away with the `-f` flag:

```
system("rm", "-r", "foo/.[^.]*")
```

Then it returns `false` and produces this:

```
rm: cannot remove `foo/.[^.]*': No such file or directory
```

---

I'm wondering if perhaps the `system` call is evaluating the negation pattern `[^.]` as literal characters or something. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any insight or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system` command passes a single string argument to `/bin/sh` for processing (not `/bin/bash`). I can't find a definitive citation, but it appears that `[^.]` would be two
literal characters, ^ and ., in `sh`. Try `[!.]` instead.

In your second and third examples, the arguments to "system" are passed directly to `exec`, and not processed by the shell, so the patterns (*not* regexes, by the way) are not expanded. In the second, the `-f` lets it ignore the fact that there is no file "foo/.[^.]*" to remove; in the third, the error is not suppressed.

Comment: Good call.  The negation pattern `[^.]` does not work under the standard shell, so that must be what `system` is using.

Do you see any problem doing something like: `system("bash -c \"rm -rf foo/.[^.]*\"")`

Comment: I would just stick with `/bin/sh` and use `system("rm -rf foo/* foo/.[!.]*")`; no sense firing up yet another process just to use "^"-style negation.

Comment: Oh, this is kind of moot, but the reason I included the second and third examples with and without the `-f` is because I thought it was odd that even though I included `-f` in my first example, it did *not* suppress the error. I just wanted to show that it *did* suppress the error in the second example. And then show that I got a different error message in the third example than I did in the first (the fact that args are passed to `exec` in the second and third examples explains this).

The outstanding oddity still remains that it produced an error in the first example despite the `-f` flag.

Comment: `-f` only ignores nonexistent files; '..' exists, but cannot be removed.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu by any chance? It uses `dash`, not `bash`, as its system shell, and `dash` does not recognize `^` as a negation character.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15587/discussion-between-chepner-and-wyattisimo)